# I want to hide div after render call complete in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I want to hide div based on userId is null or not, I am getting userId from function. After loading html I want to hide one div based on condition.

```
render: function() {
    userId = kf.helper.getUserId();
    this.$el.html(this.template({}));
    return this;
  }
```

Here I am getting UserId

Comment: I cannot tell from your question what you are trying to do or where you are getting stuck. Please review this help page on how you can add clarity to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting userId, check if it is null and send a parameter with template calling. param send boolean. Then in your template do conditional rendering. If param is true then simply hide or show div whatever you want.